# Vim: execute command with range silently

Tags: vim, vimrc

According to the vim documentation, the [`:silent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:silent) command can be used to avoid the [`hit-enter`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#hit-enter) prompt.

The problem is that I want to silent a command that accepts a range as input, and this does not work because the range is passed to `:silent` instead of to the command itself.

---

**Example**

To open the urls in the current file or selection, I use the following mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <leader>u :w !urlview<cr>
```

where [`:w !urlview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:w_c) pipes the current file or selection to `urlview` standard input.

Now, trying to avoid the `hit-enter` prompt, I added:

```
noremap <leader>u :silent w !urlview<cr>
```

that, when invoked with a selection, rightfully responds with:

```
E481: No range allowed
```

---

Any clues on how to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can modify the mapping to insert the `:silent` *after* the initial typing of the `:w` command, just like you would probably do when typing this interactively:

```
:noremap <leader>u :w<Home>silent <End> !urlview<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Since I never saw a range used "in the middle" of a command, I assumed it was not possible :|.