# How can I unconditionally open any fold present, without errors, when invoking from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, vim, gvim, macvim, vimscript

So, this is similar to ‘[execute command with range silently](https://superuser.com/questions/585629/vim-execute-command-with-range-silently)’; but that's in a mapping, and so the solution isn't applicable to what I'm trying to do.

I'm using the [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net) PDF-viewer with LaTeX Sync, and a command like the following to jump to a corresponding line in a MacVim instance:

```
mvim --remote-silent +":%line;foldo!" "%file"
```

Unfortunately, this prints “`E490: No fold found`” most of the time. In trying to silence *that* error, though, with `+":%line;silent! foldo!"`, I'm running into *another*: “`E481: No range allowed`”.

I've also tried `try | foldo! | endtry` and similar; but all approaches I've found fail to pass the range into the `foldopen!` call. Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, lord, somebody in `#vim` on Freenode helped me out: that line going around is bugged, because `;` doesn't mean subsequent-command in Vim.

The following works as intended:

```
mvim --remote-silent +":%line | silent foldo!" "%file"
```